# What is the diff of a merge commit actually showing on GitHub?

Tags: git, github, merge, version-control, dvcs

Consider the following commit page:

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/commit/cc5b002a5140e2d60184de42554a8737981c846c

Typically with Git, a commit is a set of changes applied on top of a previous codebase, so, considering the following tree:

[image]

Looking at the diff of `1ca1b6b` would show the codebase as of `ca2cac9` on the left, and the changes applied in that commit on the right. With a merge commit, what are we seeing on the left hand side? i.e. considering the following tree:

[image]

If we view commit `1e25f98` on GitHub, what's on the left? `06f5be1`? And what about with a more complicated tree? Or a merge between three branches? Does it just show a diff between the last common point in history?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[petrpulc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51081538/1256452) is correct in substance and I've upvoted it, but to address GitHub specifically, what GitHub does to show this diff is to ignore the second parent entirely.

You can see the same diff on the command line using:

```
git log -p --no-walk --first-parent -m cc5b002a5140e2d60184de42554a8737981c846c
```

or, simpler:

```
git show --first-parent cc5b002a5140e2d60184de42554a8737981c846c
```

(We need the `--no-walk` in `git log` to prevent Git from looking at more commits, while `git show` implies it.  We need the `--first-parent` to make Git look only at the first parent, and for `git log`, we need `-m` or `-c` or `--cc` to force `git log` to show a patch, as `-p` normally skips showing patches for merges, even if we use `--first-parent` to trim away the remaining parents.)

Answer (score 6):

**Git commits are, in fact, snapshots**

... because of that, you need to specify two commits to make a diff from. E.g. `git diff HEAD^ HEAD`. Second reference is set to HEAD if not specified.

But yes, for example `git log -p` shows the patch with regard to the **first parent** to make things easier. And GitHub/Lab behaves just the same.

**Parents are ordered**

And the first parent of merge commit points to the commit you were standing on before calling `git merge`. (Where your HEAD was.)

By default, the first parent is always taken. For example `HEAD^` is the first parent of `HEAD` (on the second image `6f01964`), `HEAD~2` is the first parent of first parent of `HEAD` (`2bb48b5`). This can be overridden by `^<number>` so `HEAD^2` is the second parent of `HEAD`, thus `b0417C3`.

Comment: If git commits are snapshots, why does cherry-picking a commit only cherry pick the changes made in that commit?

Comment: @LeonAves cherry-picking (btw, also used internally in rebase) is an exception that uses the introduced changes, as described in documentation. It would not make much sense to cherry-pick commit content :)

Comment: Actually, `git log -p` shows *no diff* by default. (Clone the repo in the post and try it, `git log -p --no-walk cc5b002a5140e2d60184de42554a8737981c846c`.) GitHub chooses to, in effect, use `git log -p --no-walk --first-parent -m cc5b002a5140e2d60184de42554a8737981c846c` so as to diff against the first parent.

Comment: @LeonAves: `git cherry-pick` uses the (single) parent of the commit to find the patch (though, technically, it does a full three-way merge, using the parent as the merge base). If and when you cherry-pick a merge commit, you must specify *which parent* to use for this operation, using the `-m` argument (which is forbidden if the commit is *not* a merge, which is a bit odd since `-m 1` would make sense there).